# Eclipse run configuration file exists in workspace

Tags: eclipse, workspace

I copied a couple of launch configurations (created by the same eclipse version) from another workspace into my current workspace, but I can't get them to show up on the UI.

And I am sure it is at the right place because it's where the config created in this workspace is located as well (That is, it is at ./.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches )

How do I get the copied configuration files to show up on the UI?

Comment: As @David M. Karr said, use the export/import route.  Eclipse keeps the state of the workbench in the .metadata folder of the workspace and there are hundreds of files in there for every type of config state.

Answer (score 0):

Don't copy Eclipse configuration files like that.  Use the "Export" function in the old workspace and "Import" in the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'File > Export > Run/Debug > Launch Configurations' to export one or more launch configurations.

Use 'File > Import > Run/Debug > Launch Configurations' to import one or more launch configurations.

Answer (score 0):

`.metadata` isn't meant for human manipulation. You can specify that a launch configuration should live in a workspace as a regular workspace file from the `Common` tab in most launch configurations, then just copy them across as part of the containing project.